# jquery.each - passing the counter to child .onload function

Tags: javascript, foreach, closures

somehow my counter variable is not passed to the child function. i'm guessing it's because of some asyncronous behavior but actually i have no clue.
please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgArray = new Array();
    $("canvas").each(function(i) {
        imgArray[i] = new Image();
    });
    $.each(imgArray, function(i) {
        alert(i);
        //correct output

        this.onload = function() {
            alert(i);
            //"undefined"

            var width = this.width,
                height = this.height;
            var context = $("canvas")[i].getContext("2d");
            //here's the error

            /* more code */
        };
        this.src = "PATH";      
    });
});
```

so how can i pass the value for the right canvas?
thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is due to the nature of how JavaScript supports closures. That is not to say that the problem is a bug; it's behaving exactly as it's should. The `onload` method is being executed after `i` has already been iterated all the way through and becomes `undefined`. A viable solution is to use closures to your advantage and wrap the function creation in a call, such as `this.onload = (function(index) { /* ... */ })(i);`

This guarantees that the value is stored as expected in an variable internally accessible to the `onload` methods you're creating.

Answer (score 0):

correct this part of yours to this part.

```
   this.onload = (function(a) {
            alert(a);
            //"undefined"

            var width = this.width,
                height = this.height;
            var context = $("canvas")[a].getContext("2d");
            //here's the error

            /* more code */
        })(i);
```

I created a closure so that the `i` value will be catched as it was on the loop iteration.

I will supply a simple example :

```
var i=0;

i++;
alert(i) //1

i++;
alert(i) //2


alert(i) //2 !!!
```

this is what actually  happens in you code.